# Domain on NameCheap, Hosting on GoDaddy: Redirect Loop

Tags: redirects, url, dns, godaddy, namecheap

I tried searching, but since I'm pretty new to networking I may not have used to right keywords, so I apologize if I missed the answer.

My friend owns a domain `friendsmusic.com` and I have hosting at `mydomain.com/friend` I want him to point to.

All my code uses relative paths, but I want to make sure when someone visits `friendsmusic.com` they see the page I'm hosting, but the URL in their address bar remains `friendsmusic.com` and when they click on the `contact` page the address bar reads `friendsmusic.com/contact` and not `mydomain.com/friend/contact`

At the moment NameCheap has an alias setup to my hosting, but it's resulting in a redirect loop.  Note that I don't have any code which redirects.

Anyone know what the DNS/etc. settings should be?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of here is a server alias.

A server alias points to your domain name on web server level. It can send the user somewhere without the URL changing

But you must note:

- the domain should be hosted at your hosting company
- you should redirect all links to `example.php/`. Note the **/**, otherwise the real URL will be shown.

It's a decent alternative for frames.

Answer (score 1):

It's not strictly a DNS setting. You would have to change the settings on your web server.

You will need to have the `friendsmusic.com` DNS A record point to the IP Address that `mydomain.com/friend` is hosted at.

Then assuming you are using an Apache web server you can go into the configuration file `example: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and create a [mod_rewrite condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8950841/927620). I suppose you might be able to create an .htaccess file instead of directly editing your server configuration file which you may not even have access to depending on your host. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6325389/927620) as well.